# Problem at first time going to facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

What I am having problem is that when a user first time login to this facebook iframe app then he is sent to a blank page with a facebook logo. Followin is screen shot.
[image]

Following is my code, I am using new PHP Sdk:

```
            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
              'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxx',
              'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              'cookie' => true,
            ));
            $this->facebook=$facebook;
            $this->session = $facebook->getSession();              
            $this->me = null;
            // Session based API call.
            if(!$this->session){
               if (!$this->session) {
            //echo $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($par);
               $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                    array(
                    'canvas'    => 1,
                    'fbconnect' => 0,
                    'display'   => 'page',
                    'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history'
                    ));
               $this->request->redirect($loginUrl);
            }
            }
            if ($this->session) {
              try {
                $this->uid = $facebook->getUser();
                $this->user = $facebook->api('/me');
              } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't redirect to the loginUrl, what you are essentially doing is making your iframe goto a facebook page resulting in facebook in an iframe of facebook. and facebook does not display inside an iframe. so the auth page is not shown.

you need to do a top level redirect.  basically redirecting the entire page, not just your iframe. one way to do top level redirect from inside an iframe is to show the following javascript:

```
  <html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.top.location.href = "<your redirect url here>";
    </script>
    <noscript>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<your redirect url here>" />
      <meta http-equiv="window-target" content="_top" />
    </noscript>
  </head></html>
```

Comment: I will today try this but it is very similar to what I was thinking so I think it must work